# How to host asp.net webapi project with the current build on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment

I want to host my ASP.Net Web api project on IIS for local development. I have an angular UI that wants to access this API. So for this reason I don't want to run my ASP.Net project all the time, if it were running on IIS would be better. I read many articles but none of them seemed to resolve my problem.

I know how to publish my project and then host the published version of the current build but what I don't want to do is having to do a publish every time I build just to test my code.

If I am not mistaken there is an option for deploying a new version of my project with every build. Again I don't want it to be production ready, I only need it for local development to test my API.

When I was using the publish > host currently published version on IIS the application was running.

When I was configuring IIS to point to the application folder where the solution is found as well (that is what I saw in an article about configuring IIS) I got: "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/backend-web-api-with-c-step-by-step-tutorial This is where I saw that I can configure IIS to point to my project folder.

Comment: I got it working, what I had to do is provide the "host name" that I set in IIS to the hosts file in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Comment: If you found the answer, post it below and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

1. Go to IIS Manager in windows
2. On the left hand side of the panel, right-click -> add new website
   [image]
3. Add a Site name that you like
4. Set up a Physical path, that should point to your project folder (so not where your solution is but where your ASP.Net project is)
5. Add a unique port that number that you make sure you are not currently using
6. Add a host name, and register it in the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file with your local ip address